# Property [name] does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show my product in a single page but I have "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance." error

blade:

```
<div class="title">
    <h2>{{ $singleproduct->name }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="single-product-price">
    <h3>{{ $singleproduct->price }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="single-product-desc">
    <p>{!! $singleproduct->explain  !!} </p>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $singleproduct = Singleproduct::get();
    return view('UI.store.SingleProduct' , compact('singleproduct' ));
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('/singleproduct/{product}' , 'admin\SingleproductController@show');
```

Comment: you don't have one Singleproduct, you have a collection that could have many Singleproduct ... a Singleproduct might have a 'name' but the Collection of them does not ... `get` always returns a Collection ... if you want 1 single result you can use `first` (which could return `null`)

Answer (score 2):

You have a Collection of potentially many or no `Singleproduct`s. If you only want 1 you would use `first`.

Most likely because this is a `show` route you want a specific `Singleproduct`, which I will guess you are passing an 'id' via the URL.

```
public function show($product)
{
    $singleproduct = Singleproduct::findOrFail($product);

    return view('UI.store.SingleProduct', compact('singleproduct'));
}
```

Now in the view you know that `singleproduct` is definitely an instance of `Singleproduct` and is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select only one product not all of them,
so you can update your `show` method like this

using the `route model binding` you can read more about this awesome feature in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding)

```
public function show(Singleproduct $product)
{
   return view('UI.store.SingleProduct' , compact('product' ));
}
```